# Change VMware vSphere Network Label via CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, vmware-vsphere

Does anyone have an example of how to change a Vmware vSphere VM's network label (i.e. vlan) from a CLI in Linux?

I've come across VMware's perl SDK, but rather than learn it from scratch and trawl through the dense documentation I was hoping someone may have an example which does the job. Perl wouldn't be my first choice (which also slows me down).

Any help appreciated.

**Update:** I've come across *vmreconfig.pl*, which looks like it **should** do the job, but I haven't seen any example of how it can manage network ports.

Comment: What version of VMware? VMware is a company, not a product. "VMware Workstation" is a product, as is "VMware Player", "VMware ESX", "VMware Server", et al. Please choose an appropriate tag, such as vmware-workstation, vmware-player, vmware-vsphere, vmware-server.

Comment: @Jed - my mistake! Amended as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some serious googling, perl bashing and a little despair I hit on [this forum post](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vijava/forums/forum/826592/topic/4439145), and in particular of interest, [this script](http://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/1602294-42723/updateVMDVPortgroup.pl).

**Usage:**

```
./updateVMDVPortgroup.pl --server 10.10.15.15 --vmname development-3 \
   --vnic 1 --portgroup dvPortGroup-Inside --dvs dc1-cluster-e01-dvSwitch2
```

Just the job!

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not the *VM's* 'network label' that you need to change but the appropriate vSwitch's port group - obviously this will change this name for all VMs that use that port group.

That said I've trawled through the PERL command line reference and cannot find a way to do this at all sorry, only through the GUI. That said I did find in [THIS](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/index.html), under the 'Managed Object Type'/'Network' there's a method called 'Rename_Task' - I think that's how they do it via the GUI.

Of course be aware that doing this to a single host will break vMotion/DRS as these require the port groups to be identically named across a cluster.

Comment: I'm not needing to change the label name itself, instead I need to move the VM's NIC from one label to another (i.e. move it into a difference network). A lot of the tools I've found so far reconfigure the host machine's NICs, not the VMs.